# Why is there a collision between John Smith and Sandra dee in these hash table examples?

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

So an extremely popular example when introduction hash table or hash function is the phonebook example with John Smith and the others.

My question is why is there a collision between John Smith and Sandra Dee?

Looking at this example

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hash_table_5_0_1_1_1_1_0_SP.svg

I'm thinking (521+1234)mod256 would be 152, that is way off (it's 219). I understand this is to demonstrate a collision, but why is there one in the first place? What's the formula inside the hash function?

edit: Also there's another example where they both map to 2 instead.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#mediaviewer/File:Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg

Answer (score 1):

There is no hash function in these examples, they are just contrived examples.  The hashes are totally made up.

The source code that generated your [first example](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hash_table_5_0_1_1_1_1_0_SP.svg) is [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Jorge_Stolfi/make-hash-table-figure).

If you look inside of `choose_keys_and_hashes` you'll see the line:

```
tb.key_hsh = [ 152, 001, 254, 154, 153 ]
```

So the hashes are just stored in an array.   That is followed by the lines:

```
if op.collisions :
  # Make "Sandra Dee" collide with "John Smith":
  tb.key_hsh[3] = tb.key_hsh[0]
```

So the "collision" is totally fake.  The second example seems to be generated from the same script with nkeys = 4.

Faking it is much easier than finding inputs and coming up with a hash function that gives you the desired output.